# oracle bitand function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confused about the oracle bitand function. I know it is used to cıntrol whether two bits are set. But, what is the meaning of being set. When and why it is used. If you can gve an example based on a real example, it will be so pleasent for me. Thank for your answers.

Comment: @thejartender - I am sorry for your negative experiences on StackOverflow.  I'm sure there are reasons for the changes people have made to your questions.  When I have an opportunity (and I'll make time this week), I'll see if I can can go through the questions on your profile and attempt to provide constructive feedback; either to help your for future questions, or to refute unconstructive comments made by others.

Comment: I am sory for these condition. @Dems, If you are meaning saying "solved" as an answer I did not have a chance to solve my problems by the answers from the stackoweflow. However their answers were helpful to find out a solution after I added my methods and I have gave them positive votes. There were no exact answer from users and I did not accepted them not to mislead other readers or users.

Comment: @gipsydipsydoo In that case you can stull 'upvote' helpful questions and use the 'comment' facility to aid in reolving your issues. This site is not a hand-out. You must be proactive :)

Comment: @sanalism I am going to attempt to provide you an example. One that I am seeing the product that I use.
http://myprogrammingexp.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/bitwise-operations-in-databases/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In binary, "set" means "has the value 1".  "Not set" means "has the value 0".

From the Oracle docs for BITAND:

"The result is computed in several steps. First, each argument A is replaced with the
value SIGN(A)*FLOOR(ABS(A)). This conversion has the effect of truncating each
argument towards zero. Next, each argument A (which must now be an integer value)
is converted to an n-bit two's complement binary integer value. The two bit values are
combined using a bitwise AND operation. Finally, the resulting n-bit two's complement
value is converted back to NUMBER."

Put simply, this function truncates its arguments, converts them to a binary number (currently limited to 128 bits), AND's the two binary numbers together, and returns the result of converting the binary number back to a NUMBER.

Here's the result of all possible combinations of zero and one:

```
SELECT BITAND(0, 0) AS "0, 0",  -- i.e. 0 AND 0 = 0
       BITAND(0, 1) AS "0, 1",  -- i.e. 0 AND 1 = 0
       BITAND(1, 0) AS "1, 0",  -- i.e. 1 AND 0 = 0
       BITAND(1, 1) AS "1, 1"   -- i.e. 1 AND 1 = 1
  FROM DUAL;
```

A more complex example would be ANDing together 11 and 5.  In binary, 11 decimal becomes "1011".  5 decimal becomes "0101" binary.  If you AND these values together, as in

```
1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
-------
0 0 0 1
```

you get 1 binary, which is still 1 when converted back to decimal.

Share and enjoy.