# JPA - Oracle bit operations using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, bit-manipulation

I am using CriteriaBuilder to query DB dynamically, all predictions are generated dynamically.

Only problem I am facing now is to transform this native oracle SQL to CriteriaBuilder API.

BITAND example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617716/810277

Kindly someone suggest me a way to use JPA CriteriaBuilder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of JPA do you use?

Comment: I use JPA 2.0, according to your answer, I must fetch the records first then do bit operation on each record iteratively and filter out results?

Comment: +1. I don't understand why voting against this question. Doing bitwise is important and very basic task and its weird that jpa doesn't support it

Answer (score 3):

You can use a math trick to do the same thing (a bit slower though):

Facts:

- division by 2^х will shift the bits right by x (example
  1011010/1000=1011)
- z mod 2 = 1 if rightmost bit is 1 (example 1011 mod 2 = 1)

So in Criteria API it would be like this:

```
    int mask = 0b00100;
    Path<Integer> fieldToTest = root.<Integer>get("fieldToTest");
    Expression<Integer> div = cb.quot(fieldToTest, mask).as(Integer.class);
    Expression<Integer> mod = cb.mod(div, 2);
    Predicate maskMatched = cb.equal(mod, 1);
```

Comment: This internally creates the query which has cast(x/y as signed) in the WHERE clause which returns value 1 if x/y >= 0.5. I want the return value to be 0 if x/y < 1.  There is no floor method in CriteriaBuilder. Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In JPA 2.0 that is not possible within JPQL/Criteria API. You will have to:
1. either do that logic in Java.
2. use native queries for that.

In JPA 2.1 it was introduced the `function()` method in the Criteria API/JPQL that you could use.